# How do I write SCOM 2007 R2 probes in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, monitoring

I'm trying to extend SCOM 2007 to run some .NET code that I've written.  This code can interrogate the state of an internal system and return its status.

I'm new to SCOM and can only find ways of achieving this via an action probe that executes my code as a command.  This can then captures some results which, for anything non-trivial, must be interpretted with a powershell script.

Does anyone know of a better way of doing this?  Any helpful links would be much appreciated!

Thanks!